# Is there a way to get a tilde to span characters in the way an overbar does?

Tags: formatting

I want this to work for textual input.  This screen-scrape shows what I want: 
[image]

It's not all that uncommon in mathematical literature.  Can it be accomplished in Mathematica V10?

Comment: I think only \\[OverParenthesis], \\[OverBracket] and \\[OverBrace] are supported.

Comment: You can use `OverTilde` to get some of the way, but it doesn't span like you suggest.